# Euclidean N-D Space to Model Great-Circle Distances

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, spherical-geometry

*Assuming you have a graph and know the distances between the points. 
You know that they can roughly be modeled as points on the 2D surface of a sphere by treating the distances as great-circle or orthodromic distances, but not quite.*

**How effectively could we use an euclidean N-D space to model great-circle distances?**

I guess my question would be answered by a graph/chart that plots the deviation/error by distance and dimension.

Comment: I suspect it might never work. if we set/start with the distance between north and south poles, any points on the equator will always fall on the line between north and south, i.e: all points on the equator will collapse into one point, in any dimension.

Comment: maybe if we use the largest regular polytope in the dimension as a sort of backbone?